# Renderer having image and hyperlink together in extjs

Tags: extjs

I have a form which has a displayfield.The value of the form is set as a hyperlink.Now I also need an image to appear along with the hyperlink.How can this be done?Below is my code to add hyperlink:

```
     xtype:'displayField',
     fieldLabel: 'Name',
     value: 'abc',
     renderer:function(value){
     return '<a href="#">'+value+'</a>'   //need to add an image with this
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually go for one of these approaches, mostly equivalent:

1. Add a css class to my `a` element, with `background-image` and some `padding-left`.
2. Enclose the anchor element in a `div` with a similar css class.
3. Add a `span` before the anchor. Additionally use `display: inline-block` and give it a `width` and a `height` since it has no text content.
4. You could just precede it with an `img`, but for some reason I never do that. It's ugly if the image doesn't get loaded.

Examples:
CSS

```
.myimgclass: { 
   background-image: url(...);
   background-position: 0;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
 }
 span.myimgclass {
   width: 16px;
   height: 16px;
   display: inline-block;
 }
```

So in your renderer you can the following:

Inline the anchor:

```
renderer:function(value){
 return '<a class="myimgclass" href="#">'+value+'</a>';
 }
```

Enclosed in a div

```
renderer:function(value){
 return '<div class="myimgclass"><a href="#">'+value+'</a></div>';
 }
```

Prepended as a span:

```
renderer:function(value){
 return '<span class="myimgclass"></span><a href="#">'+value+'</a>';
 }
```

Prepended as an img:

```
renderer:function(value){
 return '<img src="../your/img/path/here.png." /><a href="#">'+value+'</a>';
 }
```

I would also like to add that all these approaches are based on you wanting to add the image as html, through your renderer. Another approach is to set your component's `html:` configuration. Then use `ctrl.update('...');` if you ever want to update it. The html content should be identical to the examples above, but `value` won't be available. So `renderer` is more for dynamic content or generic during initialization, while `html` is controlled mostly from code (e.g. events).

Comment: thanks...Can you share a sample example of how to do it,just to clarify if i understood it correctly.

Comment: Edited my answer to provide examples